# Google cloud terminal using old pip version

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pip, environment

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app on google cloud and need some dependencies to be installed. This is the error message when I run `gcloud app deploy`:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask==2.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.9, 0.10, 0.10.1, 0.11, 0.11.1, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.4, 0.12.5, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3)
Step #1: ERROR: No matching distribution found for Flask==2.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Step #1: WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.2; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
```

It says that I'm using an older version of pip, but I've upgraded the pip version in my venv as `pip --version` yields:

```
pip 22.1.2 from /home/user/project-name/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

How is it possible that I have the latest version of pip, but gcloud continues to use the older version? Is there another place that I need to upgrade pip so that it can find and download the required packages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 21.2.3 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688776/you-are-using-pip-version-8-1-1-however-version-21-2-3-is-available-you-should)

Answer (score 0):

If pip is already installed and still using the older version, try below command to upgrade the latest version.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```